# Read up to delimeter from a file

Tags: c++, string, file, c++11, visual-c++

I feel like an idiot for having to ask this since I've been programming with C++ for years, but I can't figure out the easiest/best way to read this data from a file. The file is structured like so:

```
firstName lastName, num1 string1 num2 num3
```

The first and last name need to be stored in a single string variable `name` as per program requirements. I know I can combine different string/file processing methods to do this but I feel like there's probably a way to do it in 1-3 lines of code that I'm completely forgetting. Everything I've tried is either invalid or really long. How do I read this in?

Comment: This does not look like a dupe (of the previously-linked question) to me. This is asking about reading up to a specified delimiter, which was not addressed in that question (or any of its answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) takes a delimeter:

```
if (std::getline(is, name, ',') && std::getline(is, rest)) {
    // successfully read both
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something really basic that I just hadn't used in a while. I kept trying variations of `is.get()` to no avail.